# How can I create a tabular report in SQL when the column names are in the database, not the query?

Tags: sql, sqlite, crosstab

http://www.geocities.com/colinpriley/sql/sqlitepg09.htm has a nice technique for creating a tabular report where the column names for the table can be coded in the query but in my case, the columns should be values from the database.  Say I have daily sales figures like:

```
  Transaction  Date     Rep Product Amount
  1            July 1   Bob A12     $10
  2            July 2   Bob B24     $12
  3            July 2   Ted A12     $25
  ...
```

and I want a weekly summary report that shows how much of each product each rep sold:

```
        A12   B24
  Bob   $10   $12
  Ted   $25    $0
```

My column names come from the Product column.  Say, any product that has a row in the specified date range should have a column in the report.  But other products -- which weren't sold in that time frame -- should not have a column of all 0s.  How can I do that?  Bonus points if it works in SQLite.

TIA.

Comment: You will need a programming language to generate the sql, especially as sqlite does not support dynamic sql. Are you using a language?

Answer (score 0):

http://weblogs.asp.net/wallen/archive/2005/02/18/376150.aspx has a good way to extract columns

Comment: I see how that works but I don't see how it helps.  I have rather the opposite problem: I want to create column names (for the crosstab) from data, not data from column names.  Maybe my query processor is a little slow today.